# Плохо работает click() в JQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Выводит в #test следующее:

`<a class="page" href="/test.php?page=1">1</a>
<a class="page" href="/test.php?page=2">2</a>`

```
$.get('test.php',  function(data) {
 $('#test').html('<div class="content">'+data+'</div>');
 // реалиовываем переход по страницам
 $('.content .page').click(function() {
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $.get(href, function(data) {
   $('.content').html(data);
  });
 });
});
```

С первого клика происходит всё отлично, а если второй раз кликнуть по `.page`, то просто будто ничего не срабатывает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по тому что блок с навигацией по страницам у вас находится в блоке .content вы заменяете элементы на которых стоит обработчик другими элементами которые уже без обработчика.

```
$('.content').html(data);
```

Думаю проблема решится если вынести навигацию по страницам за пределы блока .content

Update:

Можно еще так попробовать:

```
$.get('test.php',  function(data) {
    $('#test').html('<div class="content">'+data+'</div>');
    bindPageClick();
});

function bindPageClick() {
     // реалиовываем переход по страницам
     $('.content .page').click(function() {
         var href = $(this).attr('href');
         $.get(href, function(data) {
             $('.content').empty().html(data);
             bindPageClick()
         });
     });
}
```

Comment: @Kison, гений, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [делегирование](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('.content').on('click', '.page', function() {
    // ...
});
```

P.S. Для jQuery > 1.4, но < 1.8

```
$('.content').delegate('.page', 'click', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: @RubaXa, Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' :(

Comment: Какая версия jQuery?

Comment: Либо jQuery меньше 1.7, либо конфликт каких-то плагинов.